# printing in awk

Tags: shell-script, awk

I have a file number.txt with following record.

*Number.txt:*

```
123456,2711448,1,14-Feb-15 09:24:25,14-Jul-15 09:24:25,120,20150814163821,13-Aug-15 09:24:25,,,12-Sep-15 09:24:25,,,12-Oct-15 09:24:25,,,11-Nov-15 09:24:25,,,11-Dec-15 09:24:25,,,10-Jan-16 09:24:25,,,,,,,,,,,,12-Sep-15 09:24:25,Y
```

Now I want to use below condition in `awk` command, and if condition matches I want to print all the column.

`awk -F"," '{ if($6 == 120) print }' number.txt`

here I want to print N in last column if condition matches.

desired output is following.

*Output:*

```
123456,2711448,1,14-Feb-15 09:24:25,14-Jul-15 09:24:25,120,20150814163821,13-Aug-15 09:24:25,,,12-Sep-15 09:24:25,,,12-Oct-15 09:24:25,,,11-Nov-15 09:24:25,,,11-Dec-15 09:24:25,,,10-Jan-16 09:24:25,,,,,,,,,,,,12-Sep-15 09:24:25,N
```

Comment: What is the delimiter in your file? if comma, please rearrange your file and separate the records.

Comment: I have comma separated file.please support further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by adding the string you want to the print action, in your code it will be like below:

```
awk -F"," '{OFS=FS}{ if($6 == 120){$NF="N"; print $0}}' number.txt
```

> Here, the `{OFS=FS}` to arrange the output file, the `awk` code will check if the condition is true, if yes it will perform the action, first will change the last field `$NF` to `"N"` then `print $0` that print the whole record.

Comment: this will add another column with "N".but i want to change the "Y" to "N" if condition matches and other column should print the same value.

Comment: @user3548033 answer edited to meets your needs.

Comment: This can be golfed to: `awk -F, '{OFS=FS}$6==120{$NF="N";print}' number.txt`

Comment: To short `awk -F, '{$NF="N"}$6==120' OFS=, number.txt`